# Convert SQL to Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel

How to convert this query to Laravel query builder?

```
SELECT 
    request_product_attributes.product_id,
    products.name,
    COUNT(request_product_attributes.product_id) AS no_of_count 
FROM
    request_product_attributes, products 
WHERE
    request_product_attributes.product_id = products.id 
GROUP BY 
    request_product_attributes.product_id 
ORDER BY 
    no_of_count DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site is not a free code-writing service.  A question is considered to be good and well-presented if it includes a problem statement, along with whatever you have tried already, highlighting where you are stuck.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

```
 $trending_items = RequestProductAttribute::join('products','request_product_attributes.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(request_product_attributes.product_id) as count'),'products.name')
            ->GROUPBY ('product_id')
            ->orderby('count','desc')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();
```